# Problems with url in symfony

Tags: symfony, php-builtin-server

I'm not sure where it comes this bug but now if I try to load my project in the browser with this url "http://localhost:8000" appears just a blank page. I tried to put a die("message") in the first line of app.php and also in the app_dev.php but nothing happens. It's like is not loading these files.

If I use http://localhost:8000/app.php or http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php it works very well and shows what's suppose to show.

I'm wondering why is this happening now. I'm not sure how to fix this problem. I updated recently from 3.3 to 3.4 but not sure if this is affecting.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: check your htaccess if using apache

Comment: I never touched the htaccess... was working before... doesn't make sence for me...

Comment: How do you serve your app? Apache bin/console server:run ? php-fpm? Can you check php error logs and apache error logs?

Comment: As KNP tutorials recommend, I use bin/console server:start

Comment: Have you checked the logs in `var/logs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25515

The problem was updating to 3.4. We will have to wait to a more stable version.